# Is there an API that I can use to duplicate the "Places" functionality of iPhoto '09?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, iphoto

I saw the Apple keynote address and was very impressed by the new Places functionality that's been added to [iPhoto '09](http://www.apple.com/ilife/iphoto/). In short, it takes the geocode information from a photo and translates it into a real place. So instead of -41.51.2 or whatever, it says "Empire State Building."

It looks fun to use but it also is similar to a feature I've wanted to add to an application of my own. So, from a developer's perspective, I'm wondering if anybody is aware of what service Apple is using to resolve a "geocode to place" mapping? Or is it believed to be something that they developed in house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Since this was my question originally, and it bubbled up again recently, just editing to add the 2016 answer here... since iOS 5, reverse geocoding is available via CLGeocoder. Since iOS 6.1, forward geocoding is part of the SDK using MKLocalSearch.

The process you are referring to is called "reverse geocoding."  A reverse geocoding service takes latitude and longitude as input and returns a real world address as output.  There are several providers out there that offer this service.  Both Yahoo and Google have APIs, but restrict you to looking up address to be plotted on a Yahoo or Google map.  They also restrict you from using their APIs in a commercial application.  There are quite a few other providers that charge for reverse geocoding.  One that I currently use is http://geocoder.us

Answer (score 1):

[BrightKite](http://brightkite.com) uses the Google API (whether public or private) to turn a geolocation (captured via GPS in iPhone app or [Geode](http://labs.mozilla.com/2008/10/introducing-geode/) in-browser) into a named place, so yes it's absolutely possible.